# Dagger2 - Duplicate instance in DoubleCheck

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm using Dagger v2.12 with `dagger-android-support` with the following config:

## AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = arrayOf(
                AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
                AndroidBindingModule::class,
                AppModule::class
        )
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<App>()
}
```

## AndroidBindingModule

```
@Module
abstract class AndroidBindingModule {
    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(MainModule::class))
    internal abstract fun contributeMainActivityInjector(): MainActivity
}
```

## MainModule

```
@Module
class MainModule {

    ...

    @Provides @PerActivity
    fun providePresenter(rxLifecycle: ReactiveLifecycle, view: MainView) =
            MainPresenter(rxLifecycle, view)

}
```

## MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: MainPresenter

    ...
}
```

Analysing the memory dump, I noticed that the `MainPresenter` class has been created twice, one been referenced in `MainActivity` and `dagger.internal.DoubleCheck`(as expected) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gau56.png), but, there are a second instance referenced only in `dagger.internal.DoubleCheck` [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pQK8.png).

[image: sample1]

[image: sample2]

Why this is happening? Is this a bug, expected behaviour or some issue in my Dagger config?

Edit:
Sample repository with the issue https://github.com/ismaeldivita/dagger-test-so

Comment: Maybe you are leaking the Activity

Comment: You have missed return type on MainPresenter provider function, is it also a typo?

Comment: The type is inferred by the Kotlin, I test it and got the same result with or without it

Comment: Nah, AndroidInjection recreates the component on configuration change

Comment: Recreate the component during configuration change is not an issue, it's expected. The problem occurs when the component is created, Dagger are always invoking the @Provide methods twice for a unknown reason.

Comment: I believe you have to implement Scopes.

Comment: Can you post a simple project at github with that behavior?

Comment: @azizbekian I edited the question with a link to a sample repository, check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that you are performing `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` 2 times within your activity class. That happens, because your activity is a descendant of `DaggerAppCompatActivity`, which in turn also performs `AndroidInjection.inject(this)`.

From the [docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.10/index.html?dagger/android/support/DaggerAppCompatActivity.html) of `DaggerAppCompatActivity`:

> An `AppCompatActivity` that injects its members in `onCreate(Bundle)` and can be used to inject `Fragments` attached to it.

After omitting `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` line from your `MainActivity` class you'll get the expected output in logcat:

[image]

Comment: That's it, thank you. My fault not check the `DaggerAppCompatActivity` implementation. This error is very silent since we used to always inject the activity in the component before v2.10 and no errors/crash happens.